# degree extension over field of $p$-adic numbers

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ be a numberfield and $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=n$. When $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is the field of  $p$-adic numbers and $K_p=\mathbb{Q}_p(\theta)$, what about $[K_p : \mathbb{Q}_p]$?

Comment: The answer is going to depend on how you "transfer" $\theta$ from an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ to an extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.  For example, if $\theta = 2^{1/3}$ and $p$ is chosen such that there is exactly one cube root of 2 in $\mathbb{Q}_p$, then $[K_p : \mathbb{Q}_p]$ could be 1 or 2 depending on how you choose $\theta$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’ll give the results, with no hint of a proof:

The general situation is that if $G(X)=\text{Irr}(\theta,\Bbb Q[X])$ splits as a product of $\Bbb Q_p$ irreducibles $G=g_ig_2\cdots g_m$, then there are essentially $m$ ways of embedding $\Bbb Q(\theta)$ into some finite extension of $\Bbb Q_p$. Each of these embeddings has, associated to it, numbers $f_i$ and $e_i$, the *residue field extension degree* and the *ramification index*, respectively, and $\sum_ie_if_i=[\Bbb Q(\theta):\Bbb Q]=\deg(G)$.

You may look at this from the standpoint of the factorization of ideals in the integer-ring $I$ of $\Bbb Q(\theta)$ this way: $(p)=pI=\prod_0^m\mathfrak p_i^{e_i}$, where $\mathfrak p_1,\cdots,\mathfrak p_m$ are the distinct prime ideals of $I$ containing $p$. They’re all maximal ideals of $I$, and each $I/\mathfrak p_i$ is a finite extension $\kappa_i$ of $\Bbb F_p=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$, with $[\kappa_i:\Bbb F_p]=f_i$, the number mentioned above.

For an example, let $\theta$ be a root of the $\Bbb Q$-irreducible polynomial $G=X^4 +3X^3+3X^2+6$. Then Hensel tells us that $G\equiv (X^2+9X-1)(X^2-6X-6)\pmod{16}$. The first factor is congruent to $X^2+X+1$ modulo $2$, so generates $\Bbb F_4$, giving $f=2$, while the second factor is Eisenstein for $2$, giving a ramification degree of $2$. Both quadratic factors are $\Bbb Q_2$-irreducible. We get the result that $f_1=2,e_1=1$ while $f_2=1,e_2=2$, so that $\Bbb Q(\theta)$ has two very different embeddings into $\Bbb Q_2$.

Answer (score 1):

I think an illustrative example is to look at cyclotomic extensions. Hensel's Lemma states that if a primitive polynomial $f$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ admits a modulo $p$ factorization

$$f \equiv \bar g \bar h \mod p$$

Then it admits a factorization

$$f = gh$$

Such that $\deg g = \deg \bar g$ and $g \equiv \bar g$ and $h \equiv \bar h$.

Now we know that our residue field is $\mathbb{F}_p$ and so $x^{p-1}-1$ splits and by Hensel's Lemma it must split in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ so we already contain these roots of unity.

Now what does this have to do with your question. We have $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p) : \mathbb{Q}] = p$ but $[\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_p) : \mathbb{Q}_p] = 1$. This is not always true (check other roots of unity) but does give an example saying that it's not an immediate or easy relationship.

Comment: There are several problems in your answer. For monic integer polynomials if $\bar{f}=\bar{g}\bar{h}\in\Bbb{F}_p[x]$ and $\gcd(\bar{g},\bar{h})=1\in \Bbb{F}_p[x]$ then $f=gh\in \Bbb{Z}_p[x]$ for some lifts $g,h$. It follows from applying to the roots of $f$ the reduction $\bmod (\pi_L)$ where $\pi_L$ is the uniformizer of the ring of integers of f's splitting field. And $[\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_n):\Bbb{Q}]=\phi(n),[\Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_n):\Bbb{Q}_p]=r\phi(p^k)$ where $n=p^km,p\nmid m$ and $r$ is the order of $p\bmod m$.

Comment: If $\gcd(\bar{g},\bar{h})=1\in \Bbb{F}_p[x]$ do we obtain that the Jacobian of $(g,h) \mapsto gh-f$ is inversible for $g-\bar{g} \equiv 0,h-\bar{h} \equiv 0$ ? This is what we need to apply Hensel lemma. And I meant reducing $\bmod (\pi_L) $ the roots as well as the Galois group acting on them (the orbits being the irreducible factors) @Lubin

Comment: Damn, @reuns, as happens all too many times, I see that I misread this answer. All appologies to you and the answerer.

Comment: Once again I was careless in reading your answer, @Xabu. It’s certainly true that $X^{p-1}-1$ factors completely over $\Bbb Q_p$. On the other hand, this has nothing to do with the extension $\Bbb Q_p(\zeta_p)$ over $\Bbb Q_p$, in which the degree is $p-1$, not $1$, as indeed 
$[\Bbb Q(\zeta_p):\Bbb Q]=p-1$

Comment: I have a feeling that user Xabu uses the very unfortunate notation $\zeta_p$ to denote a primitive $p-1$-th root of unity; if that is so, the last two paragraphs of this answer are consistent, correct and give a valid extreme example that addresses the question. Please clarify this, Xabu, and if so change the notation $\zeta_p$ to $\zeta_{p-1}$. (Namely, assuming the standard meaning of $\zeta_p$ as primitive $p$-th root of unity, I agree with @reuns' and Lubin's criticisms.)

Comment: How interesting, @TorstenSchoeneberg. This does make sense.

Comment: ... although not entirely correct, as I just noticed, because of course $[\Bbb Q(\zeta_{p-1}):\Bbb Q] \neq p$ either; but at least it's $>1$ for $p>3$.